# Can't unset rows in my array

Tags: php

I'm trying to delete empty rows in my arrays, but I can achieve that. I would need some help.

Here's what I've tried :

```
        $specialites = serialize($_POST['specialite']);
        foreach($specialites as $specialite) {
            if($specialite=='')
                unset($specialites[$specialite]);
        }
```

But every time, I get error (blank page). I would need help please. Thank you !

Comment: What is in `$_POST['specialite']`?

Comment: This is an array with text in it

Comment: @Rameleu please up-vote the answer also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I check one problem that `serialize` is called first before  `foreach`, which is the actual problem. So actually you need to do like this:-**

```
 $specialites = $_POST['specialite'];
    foreach($specialites as $key=> $special) {
        if(empty($special) || $special == '')
            unset($specialites[$key]);
    }
    $specialites = serialize($specialites);
```

note:- if you called `serialize` on a variable then it will no more array type variable.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh you should remove the first block and keep the edit only as it will not help.

Comment: This looks good, but it does not unset the empty variables. I still have it displayed on my screen.. I don't know why

Comment: sorry edited. please check. one thing `$key` missed accediently.

Answer (score 4):

you need to unset the `key` not the value and dont serialize like b0s3 said

```
foreach($specialites as $key => $specialite) {
        if($specialite==''){
            unset($specialites[$key]);
        }
}
```

if this doesn't still work. you can create another variable and use it

```
$newSpecialites = array();
foreach($specialites as $key => $specialite) {
        if(trim($specialite)){ //trim spaces then check if its not empty
            $newSpecialites[] = $specialite;
        }
}
print_r($newSpecialites);
```

Comment: If the answer is really useful then up voting really appreciated. If the above answer is not giving expected result then up voting for this is really strange. @roullie

Answer (score 1):

If you `serialize` before running the loop the it will not be an array. Thats why you are getting the error(blank page). You should `serialize` it after modifying -

```
    $specialites = $_POST['specialite'];
    foreach($specialites as $key => $specialite) {
        if(empty($specialite) || $specialite == '')
            unset($specialites[$key]);
    }
    $specialites = serialize($specialites);
```

Comment: I think this will work. However, the last line will be $specialites = serialize($specialites);

Answer (score 0):

create a temperory array then populate non-empty value in it

```
$temp_array=aray();
foreach($specialites as $key=>$specialite) {
        if($specialite!='')
          $temp_array[$key]=$specialite;

    }
     $specialites=$temp_array;
```